# Why does this segfault only when I move up (and how to fix)?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sfml

I have been trying to make a basic game using SFML and C++, but when I walk upwards, my game segfaults and crashes.

The segfault occurs on line 5 of this function inside my character class:

```
bool character::collision_check(character *player, backgroundItem *obj, char direction, bool isRunning)
{
    sf::Vector2f player_pos = player->_sprite.getPosition();
    sf::Vector2f obj_pos = obj->_sprite.getPosition();
    int height = obj->height;
    int width = obj->width;

    if (direction == 'u')
    {
        if (isRunning)
        {
            if ((player_pos.y - 8) == (obj_pos.y + (height/2)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if ((player_pos.y - 9) == (obj_pos.y + (height/2)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if ((player_pos.y - 10) == (obj_pos.y + (height/2)))
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if ((player_pos.y - 8) == (obj_pos.y + (height/2)))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if (direction == 'd')
    {
        if (isRunning)
        {
            if ((player_pos.y + 8) == (obj_pos.y - (height/2)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if ((player_pos.y + 9) == (obj_pos.y - (height/2)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if ((player_pos.y + 10) == (obj_pos.y - (height/2)))
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if ((player_pos.y + 8) == (obj_pos.y - (height/2)))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if (direction == 'l')
    {
        if (isRunning)
        {
            if ((player_pos.x - 8) == (obj_pos.x + (width/2)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if ((player_pos.x - 9) == (obj_pos.x + (width/2)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if ((player_pos.x - 10) == (obj_pos.x + (width/2)))
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if ((player_pos.x - 8) == (obj_pos.x + (width/2)))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if (direction == 'r')
    {
        if (isRunning)
        {
            if ((player_pos.x + 8) == (obj_pos.x - (width/2)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if ((player_pos.x + 9) == (obj_pos.x - (width/2)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if ((player_pos.x + 10) == (obj_pos.x - (width/2)))
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if ((player_pos.x + 8) == (obj_pos.x - (width/2)))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

which is called multiple times by the walk function in my player class:

```
void player::walk(character *player, sf::View *main, backgroundItem* obj)
{
    bool canMove = true;
    bool isRunning = false;
    bool move_amount[4];
    short speed = 1;

    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LShift) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::RShift))
    {
        isRunning = true;
    }


    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
    {
        if(player->player_texture_state == 0)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[1]);
            player->player_texture_state = 1;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                move_amount[i] = player->collision_check(player, obj, 'd', isRunning);
                obj++;

                if (move_amount[i] == 0)
                {
                    canMove = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    speed = move_amount[i];
                }
            }
            if (canMove)
            {
                if (isRunning)
                {
                    speed *= 2;
                }
                player->_sprite.move(0, speed);
                main->move(0, speed);
            }
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 1)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[0]);
            player->player_texture_state = 2;
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 2)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[2]);
            player->player_texture_state = 3;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                move_amount[i] = player->collision_check(player, obj, 'd', isRunning);
                obj++;

                if (move_amount[i] == 0)
                {
                    canMove = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    speed = move_amount[i];
                }
            }
            if (canMove)
            {
                if (isRunning)
                {
                    speed *= 2;
                }
                player->_sprite.move(0, speed);
                main->move(0, speed);
            }
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 3)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[0]);
            player->player_texture_state = 0;
        }
    }

    else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    {
        if(player->player_texture_state == 0)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[4]);
            player->player_texture_state = 1;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                move_amount[i] = player->collision_check(player, obj, 'l', isRunning);
                obj++;

                if (move_amount[i] == 0)
                {
                    canMove = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    speed = move_amount[i];
                }
            }
            if (canMove)
            {
                if (isRunning)
                {
                    speed *= 2;
                }   
                player->_sprite.move(-speed, 0);
                main->move(-speed, 0);
            }
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 1)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[3]);
            player->player_texture_state = 2;
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 2)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[5]);
            player->player_texture_state = 3;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                move_amount[i] = player->collision_check(player, obj, 'l', isRunning);
                obj++;

                if (move_amount[i] == 0)
                {
                    canMove = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    speed = move_amount[i];
                }
            }
            if (canMove)
            {
                if (isRunning)
                {
                    speed *= 2;
                }
                player->_sprite.move(-speed, 0);
                main->move(-speed, 0);
            }
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 3)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[3]);
            player->player_texture_state = 0;
        }
    }

    else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
    {
        if(player->player_texture_state == 0)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[7]);
            player->player_texture_state = 1;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                move_amount[i] = player->collision_check(player, obj, 'r', isRunning);
                obj++;

                if (move_amount[i] == 0)
                {
                    canMove = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    speed = move_amount[i];
                }
            }
            if (canMove)
            {
                if (isRunning)
                {
                    speed *= 2;
                }           
                player->_sprite.move(speed, 0);
                main->move(speed, 0);
            }
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 1)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[6]);
            player->player_texture_state = 2;
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 2)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[8]);
            player->player_texture_state = 3;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                move_amount[i] = player->collision_check(player, obj, 'r', isRunning);
                obj++;

                if (move_amount[i] == 0)
                {
                    canMove = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    speed = move_amount[i];
                }
            }
            if (canMove)
            {
                if (isRunning)
                {
                    speed *= 2;
                }
                player->_sprite.move(speed, 0);
                main->move(speed, 0);
            }
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 3)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[6]);
            player->player_texture_state = 0;
        }
    }

    else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
    {
        if(player->player_texture_state == 0)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[10]);
            player->player_texture_state = 1;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                move_amount[i] = player->collision_check(player, obj, 'u', isRunning);
                obj++;

                if (move_amount[i] == 0)
                {
                    canMove = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    speed = move_amount[i];
                }
            }
            if (canMove)
            {
                if (isRunning)
                {
                    speed *= 2;
                }
                player->_sprite.move(0, -speed);
                main->move(0, -speed);
            }
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 1)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[9]);
            player->player_texture_state = 2;
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 2)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[10]);
            player->player_texture_state = 1;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                move_amount[i] = player->collision_check(player, obj, 'u', isRunning);
                obj++;

                if (move_amount[i] == 0)
                {
                    canMove = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    speed = move_amount[i];
                }
            }
            if (canMove)
            {
                if (isRunning)
                {
                    speed *= 2;
                }
                player->_sprite.move(0, -speed);
                main->move(0, -speed);
            }
        }
        else if(player->player_texture_state == 3)
        {
            player->_sprite.setTexture(player->_textures[9]);
            player->player_texture_state = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The part that I don't understand is why this only segfaults when I move up (by pressing 'w').  When I move in any other direction it works fine, even though the collision_check function goes through line 5 every single time it is called.

When debugging with gdb it tells me:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804bef3 in character::collision_check (this=0xbfffe840, player=0xbfffe840, 
    obj=0xbfffffa0, direction=117 'u', isRunning=false)
    at character_class.cpp:53
53      int height = obj->height;
```

and when I ask it to print the value of `obj->height` it says:

```
Cannot access memory at address 0xc00000d4
```

Any help you can give me with this problem would be greatly appreciated, this has been driving me mad!

**EDIT**

The problem was as stated in user2421739's answer, but as requested here is the code to make it Minimal, Complete and Verifiable:

Main.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"
#include "backgroundItem_class.hpp"
#include "character_class.hpp"
#include "player_class.hpp"

int newID(int* currentID)
{
    return *currentID++;
}

int main()
{
    int currentID = 0;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1024, 768), "Game", sf::Style::Fullscreen);
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    sf::View main(sf::Vector2f(500, 350), sf::Vector2f(300, 200));

    player player("Images/Player-0.png", "Images/Player-1.png", "Images/Player-2.png", "Images/Player-3.png",
                "Images/Player-4.png", "Images/Player-5.png", "Images/Player-6.png", "Images/Player-7.png",
                "Images/Player-8.png", "Images/Player-9.png", "Images/Player-10.png", "Images/Player-11.png");


    backgroundItem wall_1("Images/Wall-h.png", 64, 1, 500, 278, 128, 2, newID(&currentID));
    backgroundItem wall_2("Images/Wall-l.png", 1, 64, 428, 350, 2, 128, newID(&currentID));
    backgroundItem wall_3("Images/Wall-h.png", 64, 1, 500, 422, 128, 2, newID(&currentID));
    backgroundItem wall_4("Images/Wall-l.png", 1, 64, 572, 350, 2, 128, newID(&currentID));

    backgroundItem item_array[4] = {wall_1, wall_2, wall_3, wall_4};

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        player.walk(&player, &main, item_array);

        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if((event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape))
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.setView(main);
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        window.draw(player._sprite);
        window.draw(wall_1._sprite);
        window.draw(wall_2._sprite);
        window.draw(wall_3._sprite);
        window.draw(wall_4._sprite);

        window.display();
        sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(125));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

backgroundItem_class.hpp:

```
#ifndef BACKGROUNDITEM_CLASS
#define BACKGROUNDITEM_CLASS

#include "header.hpp"
using namespace std;

class backgroundItem
{
public:
    backgroundItem(string, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
    backgroundItem();

    sf::Sprite _sprite;
    sf::Texture _texture;
    int width;
    int height;
    int id;
};

#endif
```

backgroundItem_class.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"
#include "backgroundItem_class.hpp"

backgroundItem::backgroundItem(string filename, int originX, int originY, int positionX, int positionY, int width, int height, int id)
:width(width), height(height), id(id)
{
    if(!_texture.loadFromFile(filename))
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    _sprite.setTexture(_texture);

    _sprite.setOrigin(originX, originY);
    _sprite.setPosition(positionX, positionY);
}

backgroundItem::backgroundItem()
{}
```

character_class.hpp:

```
#ifndef CHARACTER_CLASS
#define CHARACTER_CLASS

#include "header.hpp"
#include "backgroundItem_class.hpp"

using namespace std;

class character
{
public:
    character(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string);
    character();

    void setFilenames(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string);
    void setTextures(string[12]);

    bool collision_check(character*, backgroundItem*, char, bool);
    virtual void walk() {};

    sf::Sprite  _sprite;
    sf::Texture _textures[12];
    short player_texture_state;

protected:
    string _filenames[12];
};

#endif
```

character_class.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"
#include "character_class.hpp"
#include "backgroundItem_class.hpp"

void character::setFilenames(std::string file_a, std::string file_b, std::string file_c, std::string file_d, std::string file_e, std::string file_f, std::string file_g, std::string file_h, std::string file_i, std::string file_j, std::string file_k, std::string file_l)
{
    _filenames[0] = file_a;
    _filenames[1] = file_b;
    _filenames[2] = file_c;
    _filenames[3] = file_d;
    _filenames[4] = file_e;
    _filenames[5] = file_f;
    _filenames[6] = file_g;
    _filenames[7] = file_h;
    _filenames[8] = file_i;
    _filenames[9] = file_j;
    _filenames[10] = file_k;
    _filenames[11] = file_l;
}


void character::setTextures(std::string _filenames[12])
{
    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            if(!_textures[i].loadFromFile(_filenames[i]))
            {
                assert(false);
            }
        }
}


character::character(std::string file_a, std::string file_b, std::string file_c, std::string file_d, std::string file_e, std::string file_f, std::string file_g, std::string file_h, std::string file_i, std::string file_j, std::string file_k, std::string file_l)
:player_texture_state(0)
{
    setFilenames(file_a, file_b, file_c, file_d, file_e, file_f, file_g, file_h, file_i, file_j, file_k, file_l);
    setTextures(_filenames);

    _sprite.setTexture(_textures[0]);
    _sprite.setOrigin(8, 8);
    _sprite.setPosition(500, 350);
}

character::character()
:player_texture_state(0)
{}

/*And character::collision_check as up there*/
```

header.hpp:

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER

#include <string.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <assert.h>

#endif
```

player_class.hpp:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_CLASS
#define PLAYER_CLASS

#include "header.hpp"
#include "backgroundItem_class.hpp"
#include "character_class.hpp"

using namespace std;

class player: public character
{
public:
    player(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string);
    void walk(character*, sf::View*, backgroundItem*);

    short player_texture_state;
};

#endif
```

player_class.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"
#include "backgroundItem_class.hpp"
#include "character_class.hpp"
#include "player_class.hpp"

player::player(std::string file_a, std::string file_b, std::string file_c, std::string file_d, std::string file_e, std::string file_f, std::string file_g, std::string file_h, std::string file_i, std::string file_j, std::string file_k, std::string file_l)
:player_texture_state(0)
{
    setFilenames(file_a, file_b, file_c, file_d, file_e, file_f, file_g, file_h, file_i, file_j, file_k, file_l);
    setTextures(_filenames);

    _sprite.setTexture(_textures[0]);
    _sprite.setOrigin(8, 8);
    _sprite.setPosition(500, 350);
}
/*With player::walk as up there*/
```

The main reason I didn't want to post it all was the length, this is as short as I can get it which still includes everything needed.

Also, thanks for everybody's help!

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Just because your program crashes on a particular line, doesn't mean that's where the bug is. The bug can be anywhere in your code, and a [mcve] is required to determine the problem. Welcome to C++.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger? Check the variable values at each step, do they have the values you are expecting for proper functionality (e.g. indices are within right bounds)?

Comment: Time to debug your program. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your move_amount array has only four elements but your loops are accessing five elements. This leads to undefined behavior and is likely to be why the code crashes.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I still don't understand though, why did that only happen while I was trying to move up?

Comment: @H.Din there will be a reason, but it'll be a complex and hard-to-determine one, and one that is pointless trying to discover. UB is UB.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, we cannot give an exact answer without more details. As noted in the previous answer, move_amount should be of length 5 otherwise the stack will be corrupted.

The debugger output may give a different clue on the crash however.

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            move_amount[i] = player->collision_check(player, obj, 'u', isRunning);
            obj++;
```

Could it be that the input argument obj is not an array or the array too short?  The obj++ will move the pointer to the next element in the array.  Similar to the issue with move_amount, going past the end will likely result in a segmentation fault.

That the pointer value spans a page boundary (0xc000000) gives more evidence for this theory.